# Are suggested edit reviewers ping-able from comments?

Tags: support, review-queues, suggested-edits, comments

Are the *reviewers* of a suggested edit pingable (`@soandso`) from the comments on the post of the suggested edit they've reviewed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, suggested edit reviewers are not pingable from an edit they've reviewed.

In [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work), it says:

> You can explicitly notify **one (1) other commenter, editor, or ♦ moderator who closed a question**.

The only way to contact a reviewer is to comment on one of their posts, or to take it to chat. Chat is better as it doesn't clutter up the comments section of a post with unrelated chatter. If you do talk in the comments section, be sure to clean up (delete & flag the comments so they don't clutter up the post).

Comment: As of this time, that text has changed: *"You can explicitly notify [a] user if they have a current...comment on the post or their name appears anywhere in the revision history (only those who have commented will show up in the auto-complete dialog though)"* Reviewers show in the revision history. Are we **sure** they aren't pingable?