# Help me understand why I received this feedback on my edit

Tags: discussion, edits, editing-help

My edit was accepted (2 to 1 votes), but I want to make sure I understand what is okay to edit, and this is probably one of my largest edits so far; so, I thought I'd post here to get more feedback.

I don't generally make a lot of edits, so I made sure to read this sidebar:

[image: How To Edit sidebar]

The changes I wanted to make were all minor, mostly word choice or other errors usually made by non-native English speakers. Here's my suggested edit:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18523108

One of the reviewers gave me this feedback:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: You'd need to ask the reviewer.  I think it looks reasonable.

Comment: How can I ask the reviewer? There's no PM system, right?

Comment: A pretty minor point: when starting a *new sentence* with an abbreviation, such as "i.e. The" and "e.g. The", the proper way to capitalize is "E.g., the ..." For the rest I only see lots of nice work here.

Comment: @bhuwanbhatt is there a reason why you rejected this edit? It seems to be a reasonable edit that actually make the post easier to read.

Comment: I'd say forget about it and move on. There aren't _just_ bad edits, but bad reviews too. This is not the case of a bad edit.

Comment: On a side note, I've seen people reject edits that aren't _perfect_, meaning they have something that's missing / wrong despite all the right. Then the reviewer goes and, instead of rejecting / accepting and improving or even skipping, rejects the suggestion in its entirety.

Comment: @abccd: pinging `@anyname` does not work here (because `@anyname` did not take part in the discussion) and [nor will it work with `@anyname` as a reviewer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262707). (... but see that question's answer's last comment. Perhaps you can?)

Comment: We probably don't need 2 dozen comments saying that that edit is fine, but since we are only about 10 comments so far, I will state that that edit is fine.  Someone had a bad day, or maybe hit the wrong button.  But you are doing fine work. Carry On.

Comment: Let me state that the fact that you are checking the outcome of an edit that was approved is commendable.  Many could learn from that level of attention to detail.

Comment: Judging by that reviewer's past content, they don't appear to be a native English speaker - so it's likely they didn't understand that your edit contained appropriate improvements.

Comment: Awesome; thanks for the feedback. I appreciate it.